# jQuery : validate date

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I am using jQuery validation plugin '**jquery.validation.js**' to validate date data type in '**date_of_birth**' field

I want to display a custom message above the "**date_of_birth**" filed as '**Age should be minimum of 16**' .

So I have written the following customised validation code :

```
{literal}
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dob", function (value, element) {
var startDate = $('#date_of_birth').val();
var finDate = 01/03/2012
var age=Date.parse(finDate)-Date.parse(startDate);
if (age >= 16){ 
    return false;
      }
      else
     {
    return true;
     }
 }, "Age should be minimum of 16");
{/literal}
```

custom validation rules:

```
rules: {        
date_of_birth: {
dob: true
}
}
```

But the sad part is that it's not working.

Please help me out...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.validator.addMethod("dob", function() {
    var minDate  = new Date();
    minDate.setFullYear(minDate.getFullYear() - 16);

    var dob =  $('#date_of_birth').val();
    if( dob  <= minDate)
        return true;
    return false;
}, "Please specify a correct DOB:");
```

and:

```
 rules: {
    date_of_birth: { required: true, dob: "date_of_birth" },
},
```

Comment: Code is good, but you have an operator going the wrong way, it should be <= because you want to make sure the birthday of the textbox is going to be less than or equal to the date you declared as minDate. You want to have ages 16 or older, not 16 or younger.

Answer (score 1):

I think [jQuery EasyDate](http://easydate.parshap.com/) is exactly what you're looking for.